# Изменить тип str на float в pandas DataFrame

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, pandas, float, dataframe

У меня в предоставленной базе есть колонка с данными о стаже вида:

```
'9 лет 9 месяцев 14 дней'
```

Я преобразовал значения во `float` циклом `for` с регуляркой:

```
for row in range(len(df)):
    target = df['Стаж работы в организации'][row]
    content = re.findall(r'\d+', target)
    content[0] = float(content[0])
    content[1] = (float(content[1]))/12
    content[2] = ((float(content[2]))/30)/12
    content = sum(content)
    df['Стаж работы в организации'][row] = content
```

Задачу это решает конечно, хоть и не быстро, но мне кажется, что должен быть более гуманный способ, раз pandas векторизирован.

Как сделать более эффективно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [180]: df
Out[180]:
             work_experience
0    9 лет 9 месяцев 14 дней
1       2 года 1 месяц 3 дня
2  33 года 6 месяцев 30 дней

In [181]: df['new'] = (df['work_experience']
     ...:               .str.extractall('(\d+)')
     ...:               .astype(int)
     ...:               .unstack()[0]
     ...:               .dot([1, 1/12, 1/30/12]))
     ...:

In [182]: df
Out[182]:
             work_experience        new
0    9 лет 9 месяцев 14 дней   9.788889
1       2 года 1 месяц 3 дня   2.091667
2  33 года 6 месяцев 30 дней  33.583333
```